# Different ways to weight probabilities or choose probability distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

A client has 3 different ads (A, B, C) for their new campaign. Whenever a user comes onto a webpage that hosts our ads, I have to choose which ad to display.

**I choose the ad to display with uniform probability**, so each ad has a ~33% chance to be displayed. The user clicks on the ad depending on which ad is displayed with a probability of x<sub>A</sub>, x<sub>B</sub>, x<sub>C</sub>.

After doing an analysis for each ad, we know that when ad A is displayed, it is clicked on 90% of the time. When ad B is displayed, it is clicked on 70% of the time. When ad C is displayed, it is clicked on 68% of the time.

| Ad | x<sub>i</sub> |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.9 |
| B | 0.7 |
| C | 0.68 |

The question is, what probability distribution should we use to **CHOOSE which ad to display next**, to (1) optimize user clicks, but (2) without losing all data/clicks for the less popular ads, like B and C. So, we can't display ad A 100% of the time to get 90% of probability of getting clicked on.

One method I have thought of is doing a weighting of probabilities. In this case, we would display ad A (0.9)/(0.9+0.7+0.68)=39% of the time.

| Ad | % of the time ad SHOULD be displayed |
| --- | --- |
| A | 39% |
| B | 31% |
| C | 30% |
| **Total** | **100%** |

However, I think there might be a better way to do it, maybe taking into account click probability difference between A and B, etc? The % should add up to 100% for A, B, C.

Answer (score 0):

I will slightly alter your notation, as it is somewhat inconsistent. Denote by $x_j$ the probability that ad $j$ is displayed and by $c_j$ the probability that the user will click on ad $j$ given that it is displayed. The goal is to find the distribution over the ads, $(x_A, x_B, x_C)$, that maximizes the eventual probability that the user will click on it (whichever is displayed), which is given by

$$
(x_A^*, x_B^*, x_C^*) = arg \max_{x_A, x_B, x_C} \sum_{j \in \{A, B, C\}} x_j c_j
$$

Unspectacularly, the solution simply concentrates all probability weight on the ad for which $c_j$ is maximal.

You can see that this outperforms your suggested approach of a weighted probability:

$$
\frac{0.9}{0.9+0.7+0.68} \cdot 0.9 + \frac{0.7}{0.9+0.7+0.68} \cdot 0.7 + \frac{0.68}{0.9+0.7+0.68} \cdot 0.68 ~ = ~ 0.773
$$

which is lower than $0.9$, the success probability if you had just displayed ad A everytime.

I guess that although optimal, the optimal strategy wouldn't allow you to collect data on all the other ads anymore. Hence, you would need to state your objective differently.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. To understand, your solution is to display ad A 77.3% of the time, right? How do we use the same formula to solve for B and C? In the real world case, the difference between A, B, C might not be as stark. There might also be less/more than three potentially displayed ads. E.g., A, B, C might be 95%, 90%, 85%. In a generalized case where A, B, C could be anything, could we generalize the formula?

Comment: The 77.3% is the probability that the user clicks on the ad if you followed your initially proposed strategy. The theoretically optimal strategy (to maximize ad clicks) is to simply always display the ad that is clicked on the most. Yet, as mentioned, this is unlikely to be practically optimal.